# Можно ли делать мобильное приложение на Javascript и PHP?

Tags: android, objective-c, битрикс, ipad, мобильные-приложения

Спрашиваю, потому что раньше работал в конторе, где делали приложение для IPAD без знания Objective-C. Использовали только html css javascript и php. Как такое возможно? Еще, по-моему, покупали Битрикс-портал для этого. И, кстати, реально работало, сам видел, заходил с IPAD

Comment: Наверное, вам нужны кроссплатфоменные движки типа phonegap или cordova. Но php там необязателен, можно создавать мобильные приложения с HTML, JavaScript, CSS, jQuery и без PHP)

Comment: @Ksenia И будет нормально работать как яндекс-карты? Без тормозов глюков?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, Что-нибудь вроде хеллоу ворлда и немного по-сложнее будет нормально работать. Для всего остального нужно нативно писать.

Comment: @post_zee странно, помню абсолютно нормально работало полноценное приложение

Comment: Ну, я несколько утрировал по поводу хеллоу ворлда, но тем не менее.

Comment: А как же "Битрикс мобильное приложение" - на нем тоже нормально работать не будет?

Comment: Можно написать на JavaScipt. Используя технологию PhoneGap,онаже Cordova.  По скорости будет работать также как Ваш браузер на мобильном, потому, что в основе технологии компонент WebView. Проблемы будут только в тех случаях когда дело коснется железа, для этого придеться или искать или писать самому на NDK плугины.

Comment: @Алексей Кременецкий А как насчет "Битрикс мобильное приложение"? Оно позволяет писать нормальное приложение?

Comment: Сейчас React Native заползает на сцену, позволяя писать логику на JS, но предоставляя интерфейс из родных для системы элементов. Но без работы с нативным кодом вы весьма стеснены в выборе элементов управления и доступной функциональности. Вот.

Comment: Насчет Битрикса я бы не советовал. Если судить по тому, что написано на сайте, эта примочка есть дополнение к веб-сайту. Да еще самостоятельно компилироваться "это" не может. Только по прямому запросу, да еще срок выполнения 1-2 недели.

Answer (score 1):

На php нет, нельзя. На JS можно и тут есть два путя. Можно делать через WebView - это просто по сути приложение-сайт с применением html, css и т.д в т.ч. JS. Проект, который вам нужен в этом случае - Apache Cordova. А можно познакомиться с технологией React Native и делать нативные приложения на JS. Но инфы по этому вопросу очень немного, даже на английском языке.

Comment: А как без php или другого интерпретируемого языка будет происходить взаимодействие приложения с сервером?

Comment: по реакт нэйтив немного инфы? даже на английском?

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko есть официальная документация, сейчас много кто развивается в сторону реакта, так что шансы есть.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев мы говорим про само приложение, как отдельную единицу. Сервер можете писать на чём угодно, но для самого приложения php не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Из того что Вы пишете видится такой сценарий: JS для мобильного приложения, php для бэкенда.
Но сейчас, при желании, можно найти что угодно как для мобильного приложения (не удивлюсь, если какой-то энтузиаст пилит аналог идеи ReactNative, только на каком-нибудь brainfuck или COW), так и для серверной части.
Важнее определить что Вам необходимо, что можете и подобрать нужный инструмент. Если Вам нужно что-то простое, как отправить/получить информацию, отобразить ее/сохранить, не нужен pixel-perfect дизайн и т.д., при этом не хотите касаться Objective-C/Swift/Java/Kotlin - возьмите React Native и пишите на JS. Хотите еще меньше вникать в некоторые особенности мобильных - берите Cordova и, можно сказать, показывайте мобильную версию сайта.